# Unable to use the OCI client in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer 23.1 on Windows 10 and I'm trying make SQL Developer use the OCI client.
I've followed all the instructions that I can find, but I get the below error when I test it

```
Testing the Instant Client located at C:\Users\brubin\Oracle\instantclient_21_11
Testing client directory ... OK
Testing loading Oracle JDBC driver ... OK
Testing checking Oracle JDBC driver version ... OK
  Driver version: 21.9.0.0.0
Testing testing native OCI library load ... Failed:
  Error loading the native OCI library
  The native OCI driver could not be loaded. The system propertyjava.library.path contains the 
entries from the environment variable PATH. Check it to verify that
  the expected native library directory C:\Users\brubin\Oracle\instantclient_21_11 is present 
and precedes any other client installations.
  java.library.path = C:\Users\brubin\Oracle\instantclient_21_11
```

I have downloaded the Instant Client version 21 to `C:\Users\brubin\Oracle\instantclient_21_11`

[image]

I have added the location to the client as the first entry in my Path

[image]

I created a `.bat` file to run SQL Developer

```
set PATH=C:\Users\brubin\Oracle\instantclient_21_11;%PATH%
"C:\Users\brubin\Oracle SQL Developer 23.1.0.097.1607\sqldeveloper.exe"
```

However, I still get the error above when I click Test in SQL Developer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to overwrite ojdbc11.jar in instant client directory with this file:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc11/21.11.0.0/ojdbc11-21.11.0.0.jar

to have corespoding version of jdbc driver with instant client.

When I tried the instanct client 21.11 with your OJDBC11 version 21.9.0.0.0, I get same error as You.
With coresponding version of OJDBC11.jar it is working for me:

```
Testing the Instant Client located at C:\Oracle\instantclient_21_11
Testing client directory ... OK
Testing loading Oracle JDBC driver ... OK
Testing checking Oracle JDBC driver version ... OK
Driver version: 21.11.0.0.0
Testing testing native OCI library load ... OK
Success!
```

Comment: Thank you.  Getting the versions to match between my JDBC driver and the Instant Client worked.