Test failed: no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path
I try to connect with sql developer
enter image description here
The native OCI driver could not be loaded. The system propertyjava.library.path contains the entries from the environment variable PATH. Check it to verify that
the expected native library directory C:...\instantclient_21_15 is present and precedes any other client installations.
java.library.path = C:...\SqlDeveloper\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;...;C:....\instantclient_18_5;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.4\bin;;C:\Users....\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;;.
lunch 
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
and the output is:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH;...;C:...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.4\bin;;C:...\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;;.
how can I fix it?
I try to add instant client 21c
enter image description here

Try to look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239365/unable-to-use-the-oci-client-in-sql-developer/77256213#comment136216614_77256213 May be it is the same situation?
